# PHP Remove all characters up to TLD

Tags: php, twig, trim, silex

I'm running a project on silex and gota little problem.

```
I get my assets path for twig with this function:

$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function ($twig, $app) {
  $twig->addFunction(new \Twig_SimpleFunction('asset', function ($asset) {

    return sprintf('assets/%s', ltrim($asset, '/'));
  }));

  return $twig;
}));
```

With this function i can use:

```
{{ asset('/images/events/1.jpg') }}
```

But this doesn't work for nested routes like

```
/events/archive
```

How can I get this work for nested routes?

Comment: The Twig function returns a relative path. A relative path is always resolved relative to the current URL, therefore this can’t work in a subdirectory. (*You* know that there is no such physical subdirectory and instead the request is served from the project’s top directory, but the *client* doesn’t.) The returned asset path must be absolute and hence include the project web root as prefix.

Comment: ah ok thx! just add a slash infront of assets was the solution :-)